transction bundles
Solana also provides bundle transactions. However, I could not find any help for sending bundle transactions using Jito bundles. Can we also send bundle transactions in an atomic way, where all transactions succeed or none at all, like creating marketed ,adding liquidity by 5 accounts in a bundle? I have been stuck on this for a week.
Thanks in advance.

I don't think Solana has bundles native and you must use Jito for your purposes.
Jito bundles will let you atomtically send up to 5 different transactions and have them all execute or none of them execute.
There is reference codeon the Jito website:
https://github.com/jito-labs/jito-python
https://github.com/jito-labs/jito-ts

Thanks for your reply - I did not get any guide for JITO bundle in JS/TS  for sending the transaction into bundles. If you have any then can you please share a link?

@Bobz https://github.com/jito-labs/jito-ts is the link to the Jito bundle SDK. I could also recommend looking at driftpy for an example usage.
